# Opening a file, and taking input from the file opened in a Python program

Tags: python, macos

I have written a program in python that is another front end for un-tarring files on OSX. I want to be able to double click on the file and open with the program that I wrote. How do I make the program automatically know that it is being opened with that file, and to work on that file?

Answer (score 0):

- You will need to make your make your script executable with the command `chmod a+x <your script.py>`
- You will also need to tell your OS that the python interpreter is needed to execute this file. In Linux the line `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of the file is what does this. I assume its the same in OSX.
- Then right click and select "Open with" and then "Other...". And select your script.

The Python script will need to be configured correctly to run when the OS calls it in this way.

Another way to do it(**Caveat**: I haven't personally tried this) is to use a shell script as advised in [this anwer](https://superuser.com/a/134599) on the superuser forums.

Comment: Unfortunately, these steps are not by themselves sufficient to get the job done, because only bundles recognizes as Mac OS X applications can be chosen in the "Open With..." dialog.  To make this work, the OP will have to use a tool like py2app to make an application bundle that contains his Python application.

Answer (score 0):

Python scripts on OS X are not by default recognized as launchable applications by the Finder.  What you need to do is use a tool that will package your Python script as a Mac OS X application.  Then, you can right-click or ctrl-click a file of your chosen file type and locate that application through the Open With... dialog.

One option I'm aware of for doing this is part of the MacPython package, called py2app:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/py2app

So, your steps would be:

1)  Use py2app to package your Python script as a launchable application

2)  Associate the application with the file type you'd like it to open using by right-clicking   or ctrl-clicking one of that file type and choosing "Open With..." in the OS X Finder.

Answer (score -3):

```
import sys
print("Program.py executing...")
for x in sys.argv:
    print(x)
```

Produces the output

```
Program.py executing...
Program.py
something.tar
```

I'm windows, running this command:

```
python Program.py something.tar
```

I don't think anything changes from that command to OSX.

And as said by benjamin, the OS is responsible for determining what program is used for the file. I don't know what the command line from your os will be, but you can find out with the above program.

Comment: How are those print statements in any way relevant?

Comment: They print the strings contained in argv, which are your command line arguments passed by the operating system. (such as the file(s) to open.)